# Iterate over rows to find patterns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  | type | val
-----------------
0 | low  | 0.5
1 | high | 1.2
2 | NaN  | NaN
3 | low  | 1
4 | NaN  | NaN
5 | high | 3
6 | NaN  | NaN
7 | low  | 2
8 | high | 4
9 | NaN  | NaN
10| low  | 3
..............
98| low  | 0.5
99| NaN  | NaN
```

What I am trying to do is find a pattern like low1->high1->low2->high2->low3 while checking if low2>low1 and high2>high1, etc... in the above dataframe and extract their values to a new dataframe.

And also if only a part of it satisfied for eg (low1->high1) but not the rest, I want to start iterate from that point on such that I don't miss any patters in between too.

I have tried using iloc to get five indices at a time and compare them using a long if statement but it doesn't look like the most efficient way to code it

```
sh = high
sl = low

for idx in range(0 ,df.shape[0] -4)
    if (sl in str(df.iloc[idx]['type'])) and (sh in str(df.iloc[idx+1]['type'])) and (sl in str(df.iloc[idx+2]['type'])) and (sh in str(df.iloc[idx+3]['type'])) and (sl in str(df.iloc[idx+4]['type'])) and (df.iloc[idx+4]['val'] > df.iloc[idx+2]['val']) and (df.iloc[idx+3]['val'] > df.iloc[idx+1]['val']) and (df.iloc[idx+2]['val'] > df.iloc[idx]['val'])  and (0.3 * (df.iloc[idx+1]['val'] - df.iloc[idx]['val']) < ((df.iloc[idx+1]['val'] - df.iloc[idx+2]['val']))) and (0.3 * (df.iloc[idx+3]['val'] - df.iloc[idx+2]['val']) < ((df.iloc[idx+3]['val'] - df.iloc[idx+4]['val']))):

        # get the 5 values here and append it the dataframe
```

An example of the final result should be:

```
  | type | val | pattern
--------------------------
0 | low  | 0.5 | l1
1 | high | 1.2 | h1
2 | NaN  | NaN | NaN
3 | low  | 1   | l2
4 | NaN  | NaN | NaN
5 | high | 3   | h2
6 | NaN  | NaN | NaN
7 | low  | 2   | l3
8 | high | 4   | NaN #NaN since this doesn't form a pattern (Our pattern always starts with a low)
9 | NaN  | NaN | NaN 
10| low  | 3   | l1
..............
98| low  | 0.5
99| NaN  | NaN
```

Comment: Is your data inputted correctly? I see a mismatch with your desired code and that which is at the head.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. You mean the for loop or with the conditional statement?

Comment: Initial data --> desired output.

Comment: Hey sorry, The previous output was supposed to be final output after I have extracted all the patterns. For now I am trying to efficiently label the highs and lows with the desired pattern.

Comment: Gotya. Additionally, I'm not sure I follow your logic for ruling out `row 8`.

Comment: We are only looking at 5 points at a time (l1 -> h1 -> l2 -> h2 ->l3) and then start over again. So in the case of ```row 8``` since it is not a low(l1), we skip it. It would be even better to start second pattern from ```row 2``` but I have no idea how to label it.

Comment: Are you reusing data points in multiple patterns? Or does your pattern travel down the column?